# Error pop-ups when accessing Fintek F81954D Super IO using Fintek System SDK

Tags: windows, embedded

I have an iBase industrial PC running Windows 11 that features a FinTek F81954D Super IO chip. I am trying to use this chip to setup the hardware watchdog (WDT).

Since `outb()` and `inb()` instructions are not available in user mode, I resorted to using the Windows version of FinTek SDK (https://www.fintek.com.tw/index.php/mnu-swdevelopkitdl).

My program works most of the time, but on some system it encounters an error and displays a pop-up:

[image: UserPrivilege Issue. Error Code: 0]

The error is not very descriptive, but the worst part is that since this is an industrial PC, there is no user and no one there to click "OK".  This causes the main thread to just hang.

Is there a way to use the SDK without popups?  Is there a way to programmatically press "OK" when this window opens?

I am still trying to figure out why it works on some systems but not on others, but these popups are really messing up the users.

Thank you for any ideas.